# dotnet Core - Need to create a generic extension method that has two generics and one being the extension

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a generic CSV conversion static method.  It has the entity - the extension.. let that be "T" however I also need to include a different context based on the entity. There are two databases each have a suburb entity and the DBs context.

How do I have two generic vars so to speak with one being the extension..
This is what I started with:

```
    public static Suburb FromCsv(string csvLine, CATALOGContext context)
    {
        if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var values = csvLine.Split(',');
        if (context.States == null) return null;
        if (values.Length <= 3) return null;
        var suburb = new Suburb
        {
            PostCode = values[0],
            SuburbName = values[1],
            State = context.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StateShortName == values[2]),
            Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[3], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
            Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[4], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        };

        return suburb;
    }
```

This is what I had but its clearly not right.

```
        public static T FromCsv<T, I>(this T source, string csvLine, I context)
        {
            if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));
            if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

            var values = csvLine.Split(',');
            if (context.States == null) return null;
            if (values.Length <= 3) return null;
            var suburb = new Suburb
            {
                PostCode = values[0],
                SuburbName = values[1],
                State = context.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StateShortName == values[2]),
                Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[3], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[4], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            };

            return suburb;
        }
```

It does not know that this is a dbContext (context) so I need to use a where clause and I am unsure how to do that. Further, each dbContext has a "State" but this is error-ing for the above reason -doesnt know its a context.

How can I have multiple generics with one being the extension - the entity and the other being the context (not even sure I can have this) where you can use it with different database contexts etc?

Comment: For one thing, returning the same type you want the extension method on doesn't seem right. In the case of `Suburb`, you would have to have an instance of it in order to call the extension method and then it returns a new instance? It's not clear to me what that is supposed to be. As for the context parameter, can you use the base DbContext type instead of a generic - doesn't the `CATALOGContext` inherit DbContext? Could you show an example of how you envision using the extension method?

Comment: Also, how would the generic extension method know which properties to set if it doesn't know the type? Or which columns map to which property? Have you looked into using an object mapper?

Comment: In my opinion this method is responsible for too many things like splitting a string, getting data from the database and creating a new instance of the class Suburb. Besides the fact that passing any context to a static method is bad practice. Is there a reason for you to use a static method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use specific entity to return T. You have to use T to return T. Why not using this simple one?

```
public enum DBcon
{
      DB1, DB2
}
public static Suburb FromCsv(string csvLine, DBcon con)
{
    var context = con == DBcon.DB1 ? new CATALOGContext() : new DB2Context();

    if (csvLine == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(csvLine));
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    var values = csvLine.Split(',');
    if (context.States == null) return null;
    if (values.Length <= 3) return null;
    var suburb = new Suburb
    {
        PostCode = values[0],
        SuburbName = values[1],
        State = context.States.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StateShortName == values[2]),
        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[3], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(values[4], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    };

    return suburb;
}
```

Comment: That will do... I am not precious regarding generics just didnt want to have two of them pretty much identical thats all. So... thankyou for putting this up.